# Google Map direction lon/lat params

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I m searching for the parameter which I can open a map window directly by putting lon/lat as the source param and get my location itself.

something like this and and draw direction on map

https://maps.google.com/maps?from=37.4219720,-122.0841430&to=GET_MY_LOCATION

Thank u

Comment: https://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:38.9419+-78.3020 here it is but still I need to get it from my own location, browser to detect my location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There  is no parameter for a automatic detection of your location, you must detect it on your own using e.g: [navigator.geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Using_geolocation)

The correct parameters are not `from`, `to` or anything else, they are `saddr` and `daddr`.

Example:

[`https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=52.5191,13.4060&daddr=52.4244,13.7497`](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=52.5191,13.4060&daddr=52.4244,13.7497)

Comment: Can u tell me how can I send marker info (content inside tooltip)

Comment: There is no option to send it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy! There is a param for autodection of your location assuming your browser supports geolocation and you haven't blocked it, as with all geolocation calls.

I'm assuming you want to pass a link directly or through an "a href" tag and not use gmaps api.

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=52.5191,13.4060&daddr=current%20Location
```

A better method would to run a test and verify geolocation is support and turned on.
Check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/bingeboy/5519841
If the success callback fires then you know the URL will work.